# How to re-size rows and columns of a html table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using  both colResizable(for adjusting column) and Resizable function(for adjusting row) it is working good in mozilla firefox but not working in chrome

For column we are using the following link - http://quocity.com/colresizable/ 
For row we are using following jquery function - `$("#tblResize2 tr").resizable();`

note : on the above code we tried using td (instead of tr) to resize columns it is not working after the final impact.

```
$("#MatrixTable").colResizable({
                onResize: onSampleResized
            });

            $("#MatrixTable tr").resizable();
            $("#MatrixTable td").resizable();
```

Whole function

```
 var onSampleResized = function (e) {

  var columns = $(e.currentTarget).find("td");
            var rows = $(e.currentTarget).find("tr");
            var full_msg;
            var row_msg;

        `columns.each(function () { full_msg += $(this).attr('id') + "_" +` $(this).width() + "_" + $(this).height() + ";"; })
        rows.each(function () { row_msg += $(this).attr('id') + "_" + $(this).width() + "_" + $(this).height() + ";"; })
        document.getElementById("hf_data").value = full_msg
        document.getElementById("hf_rowdata").value = row_msg;

    };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your `onSampleResized` function do?

Comment: The second to last line in the function is missing a `;` try the code I posted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a working sample here: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44fKg/6/)**

I think you have a few issues with the function. There were several missing `;` that chrome may have not liked, try the following.

Full Javascript:

```
$(function () {
        var onSampleResized = function (e) {
        var columns = $(e.currentTarget).find("th");
        var rows = $(e.currentTarget).find("tr");
        var full_msg = "";
        var row_msg = "";
        columns.each(function () {
            full_msg += $(this).attr('id') + ":" + $(this).width() + "x" + $(this).height() + ";\n";
        });
        rows.each(function () {
            row_msg += $(this).attr('id') + ":" + $(this).width() + "x" + $(this).height() + ";\n";
        });
        document.getElementById("hf_data").value = full_msg;
        document.getElementById("hf_rowdata").value = row_msg;
    };

    $("#MatrixTable").colResizable({
        onResize: onSampleResized
    });

    $("#MatrixTable tr").resizable();
    $("#MatrixTable td").resizable();



});
```

Comment: var onSampleResized = function (e) {
           var columns = $(e.currentTarget).find("td");
           var rows = $(e.currentTarget).find("tr");
           var full_msg;
           var row_msg;
          columns.each(function () { full_msg += $(this).attr('id')                     + "_" + $(this).width() + "_" + $(this).height() + ";"; })
rows.each(function () { row_msg += $(this).attr('id') + "_" + $(this).width() + "_" + $(this).height() + ";"; })
document.getElementById("hf_data").value = full_msg
document.getElementById("hf_rowdata").value = row_msg;            };

Comment: We have used this function(onSampleResized) to get width of td and height of tr and saved to db, when i try to access the table after impact i cant resize the table row in chrome

Comment: I updated the code and the fiddle. I think this is what you're looking for. The text that is output is formatted a little easier to read. I really think the missing `;` was presenting an issue in chrome.

Comment: please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/44fKg/5/ <br/> i have saved the tr height to 50px when i tried to reduce adjust the row it is not reduced less than 50px in chrome but it is working perfect in firefox you check it

Comment: I see that - it seems to set a minimum height in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the resizable function of the jQuery UI library. You shouldn't even need colResizable. It works with everything. Comes with JS and CSS for resizable items.

http://jqueryui.com/resizable/

Got it working in JSFiddle.